# attempting to customise Materialize css throws error

Tags: sass, materialize

I am trying to add a new colour palette to the materilize sass http://materializecss.com/color.html.

I have copied what I have seen in their sass files with a few new variables but it is not working.

in _color.scss I have added

```
$my-blue: (
    "base": #0069B1,
);
```

in _variables.scss I have added

```
$my-primary-blue: color("my-blue", "base") !default;
```

then I modified a line in the _variables.scss to use my new color

from:

```
$button-background-focus: lighten($secondary-color, 4%) !default;
```

to

```
$button-raised-background-hover: lighten($my-primary-blue, 5%) !default;
```

I then get an error in compilation

```
>> Error: argument `$color` of `lighten($color, $amount)` must be a color
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to add to a further color variable later on

```
$colors: (
  "materialize-red": $materialize-red,
  "red": $red,
  "pink": $pink,
  "purple": $purple,
  "deep-purple": $deep-purple,
  "indigo": $indigo,
  "blue": $blue,
  "light-blue": $light-blue,
  "cyan": $cyan,
  "teal": $teal,
  "green": $green,
  "light-green": $light-green,
  "lime": $lime,
  "yellow": $yellow,
  "amber": $amber,
  "orange": $orange,
  "deep-orange": $deep-orange,
  "brown": $brown,
  "blue-grey": $blue-grey,
  "grey": $grey,
  "shades": $shades,
  "my-blue": $my-blue,
) !default;
```